# Evenly sampled 3D meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3-dimensional meshgrid generated using the following code:

```
x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, x, x)
```

This generates a 100 x 100 x 100 point 3-d grid of points.  I would like to plot an evenly-space sub-sampling of this same grid, without having to generate a new grid.  My approach to this was to use `np.linspace()` to get an array of 10000 evenly-space indices from the original array to plot `xx[subsample]`, `yy[subsample]`, and `zz[subsample]`.  I used

```
subsample = np.linspace(0,len(xx.flatten())-1,10000,dtype=int)
```

However, when I pass this array my plotting function, I get uneven structure (diagonal lines) in 3-dimensions:

[image]

My guess is that this is happening because I flattened the array, and then used `np.linspace()`, but I can't figure out how to sample the grid in 3-dimensions and have it come out evenly distributed.  I would like to avoid generating a new meshgrid if at all possible.

My question is how would I evenly subsample my original 3-dimensional meshgrid, without having to generate a new meshgrid?

Comment: What's wrong with generating a new grid?

Comment: I use these positions to calculate other physical quantities, which make up additional grids.  So if I generate a new grid, I'll have to generate additional grids for those physical quantities.  I would think it would be easier to get the indices of the original grids rather than generate new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [117]: x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
     ...: xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, x, x)
In [118]: xx.shape
Out[118]: (100, 100, 100)
```

1000 equally spaced points in `xx`, similarly for all other grids:

```
In [119]: xx[::10,::10,::10].shape
Out[119]: (10, 10, 10)
```

Or with advanced indexing (making a copy)

```
In [123]: i=np.arange(0,100,10)
In [124]: xx[np.ix_(i,i,i)].shape
Out[124]: (10, 10, 10)
```

I think we could use `np.ravel_multi_index` to get an array of flattened indices.  We'd have to generate 1000 tuples of indices to do that!

I don't see how we could get a 10,000 points.  `::5` would give 8000 points.

Comment: This gets very close to what I was looking for.  I'm still trying to figure out how to generalize it so I get as close as possible to the number of points I want to sample.  For instance if I wanted to sub-sample a maximum of 10000.  It doesn't have to get exactly 10000, but as close as possible.

Comment: Take every 4.6th one in each dimension :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying using [arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)? Using linspace for integers may have some rounding issues.

Could you try the following?

```py
subsample = np.arange(0, xx.size, xx.size // 10000) # the last parameter is the step size
```

Also, be sure that `xx.size` is divisible by `10000`, which is the case for your 100x100x100.

Tip: use `.size` to get the number of elements in an array. Use `.ravel` instead of `.flatten` as the latter creates a copy but [ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) is just a view.

Edit: That subsample did not generate those diagonals but it just got a plane.

```py
subsample_axis = [np.arange(0, xx.shape[i], 10) for i in range(len(xx.shape))]
subsample = np.zeros([len(axis) for axis in subsample_axis])
for i, axis in enumerate(subsample_axis):
    shape = [len(axis) if j == i else 1 for j in range(len(xx.shape))]
    subsample += axis.reshape(shape)*np.prod(xx.shape[i+1:])
subsample = subsample.ravel().astype('int')
```